# What does "a que nadie" mean?

Tags: traducción, modismos, letras-de-canciones

I'm listening to a [Christian children's song](http://tealabamos.com/moises-y-el-mar-rojo/) that has the following lyrics:

> A que nadie sabe cómo
>   Moisés atravesó el mar Rojo [...]
>   ¿Lo nadó? (no, no)
>   ¿Navegó? (no, no)
>   ¿Patinó? (no, no)
>   ¿Cómo lo atravesó?

I can't figure out how to translate "a que nadie" in the first line.  Does it mean "Does anyone...?"  Or something else?

Comment: I'd say: I bet nobody knows how... (Actually, it comes from: Apuesto a que nadie sabe cómo...)

Comment: I agree with Diego and Gustavson, it means "I bet no one knows."  But for this song, I'd express it as: *Can anyone tell me ...?*  Because this lyric suggests interaction with a group of children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means sort of "Does anyone...?", but the connotation is

> [I bet/I'm sure that] no one knows ...

The "A que nadie (XYZ)" is some sort of "challenge question", as opposed to a statement, in which you imply your certainty that no one has (done) XYZ.

- A que nadie tiene más puntos que Charlie aquí  <sub>(I bet/I'm sure that) No one here has more rep points than Charlie</sub>
- A que nadie sabe la solución a este acertijo  <sub>(I bet/I'm sure that) No 
  one know the answer to this riddle</sub>

> A que nadie sabe cómo Moisés atravesó el mar Rojo

could be translated as

> I'm sure that no one here can tell me how Mosses parted the Red Sea

The expression is a shortening of "Apuesto a que [esto sucede]"

> (Apuesto) A que nadie XYZ

which conveys certainty of an outcome or situation.

Comment: Could you add what Gustavson said?   That it comes from *Apuesto a que*?

Comment: Sí, yo también he pensado en eso. Sin embargo ahora leyéndolo he empezado a divagar un poco... resulta que ese tipo de estructura se usa en preguntas "¿a que nadie sabe...?" con el mismo significado de "¿verdad que nadie sabe...?". ¿Cómo se pasa de una afirmativa (apuesto a que) a una interrogativa? ¿Puede tener en realidad otro origen? ¿o hay algún otro nexo diferente? Es simplemente una pregunta que se me acaba de ocurrir al hilo de tu respuesta.

Comment: no creo que deba ser utilizado como pregunta, dado que son afirmaciones desafiantes,  por ejemplo, "a que no sabes que es esto, ¿verdad?" , la pregunta no esta en el reto, lo unico que se pregunta es la afirmacion de lo que se acaba de decir. incluso , no se necesita preguntar el "verdad"

Comment: Mike, no sé si estoy en completo acuerdo. "Apuesto a que nadie ..." es una afirmación, mientras que "A que nadie ..." tiene forma de pregunta, aunque solo sea para esperar la confirmación de algo de lo que estás seguro (o corroborar que nadie te lleva la contraria o está en desacuerdo). "A que no sabes qué es esto" o "A que son las tres y cuarto" son preguntas. Otra cosa es que sean prácticamente **retóricas** pues quien las hace está seguro de la respuesta que va a ser dada.